# Write to array simultaneously in python

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def f(a, i):
    a[i] += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    N = 10
    a = mp.Array('i', xrange(N), lock=False)
    print "a =", [elt for elt in a]
    jobs = [mp.Process(target=f, args=(a,i)) for i in xrange(N)]
    for job in jobs:
        job.start()
    for job in jobs:
        job.join()
    print "a =", [elt for elt in a]
```

Every time I run this code, i get the expected result:

```
a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Is it fine to simultaneously write to `a` without a lock since write indices will always be different, or is that not okay, and what's happening is that, coincidentally, each process writes to `a` at a slightly different time, yielding the right result?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should consider using `multiprocessing.Pool`s `map` function for this purpose
Your code will transform to something like

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool(process=PROCESSCOUNT)
a = p.map(f, a))
```

It's much clearer and in this case there is no need to use `multiprocessing.Array` you can use regular python list